# Unsaved NSManagedObject life cycle after context save failure

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Supposing I had a failure in saving an NSManagedObjectContext, due to a reason independent by the data itself. A classic example would be not enough space left on device.

It is my understanding that the NSManagedObjects still reside in memory, in unsaved state.

These are the question that follows:

1. What does happen to the objects ? Are they at risk of suddenly being evicted from memory, in particular when the app is in background ?  If yes, is there a kind of notification when this happens ?
2. How do you manage an event like this or similar ones that are not due to the program itself ?
3. Is it possible to mimic this particular behavior (not enough space) during XCode development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does happen to the objects ? Are they at risk of suddenly being evicted from memory, in particular when the app is in background ? If yes, is there a kind of notification when this happens?

Objects don't get evicted from memory. **Apps** can be evicted from memory if they're in the background. When that happens, all of the app's objects disappear as well. Notifications would follow the same rules as normal app life-cycle notifications-- those posted by `UIApplication` and sent as callbacks to the app delegate.

> How do you manage an event like this or similar ones that are not due to the program itself ?

There's not a lot you can do. If there's no space on the device, you can't save data. The only real option would be if you have some other saved data that you could delete, to make some space. If that's not an option, you're out of luck, because there's no place to put this unsaved data.

> Is it possible to mimic this particular behavior (not enough space) during XCode development ?

Take a test device and fill it up with data, then run your app.